# How to make events fire when an HTML video reaches a certain time mark?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering whether this is even possible, and if so, how it would be done. So I have an HTML5 video on my page

```
<video id="ssvid">
      <source src="assets/Cisco_SmartStack_04012016_NoText_2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

and let's say I want functions to be invoked at the 2-, 13- and 15-second marks of the video playing. I'm trying to create an object like

```
$(function(){
    window.VidHandler = (function(divid){
        this.divid = divid;
        this.PauseFunctions = [
            {
                SecondMark: 2,
                OnSlideTo: function () { },
                OnSlideAway: function () { }
            },
            {
                SecondMark: 13,
                OnSlideTo: function () { },
                OnSlideAway: function () { }
            },
            {
                SecondMark: 15,
                OnSlideTo: function () { },
                OnSlideAway: function () { }
            }
        ];
    })("ssvid");
});
```

but I don't know if JavaScript has an `"ontimemark(2)"` type of event listener that I can set up. Will I have to create a `setInterval` to do this?

Comment: What's `dvid` supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to make events fire when an HTML video reaches a certain time mark?

Use [`currentTime` and `timeupdate`](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/) see the demo utilize both.

> but I don't know if JavaScript has an "ontimemark(2)" type of event listener that I can set up.

`timeupdate`

> Will I have to create a setInterval to do this?

No, see **Snippet** below.

- Every `timeupdate` event fires the `console.log`
- `vidHandler()` uses a `switch` to fire on second marks 2, 13, and 15.
- You can replace the `console.log`s with the slide methods.
- By the looks of it, `currentTime` looks more like `1sec = 3.5sec`? Or the reported duration for the video element is inaccurate.

**Snippet**

```js
  var ssvid = document.getElementById('ssvid');
  var tick = ssvid.currentTime;

  ssvid.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    console.log('currentTime: ' + tick);
    tick++
    vidHandler(tick);
  }, false);


  function vidHandler(time) {
    switch (time) {
      case 2:
        console.log('2 second mark');
        break;
      case 13:
        console.log('13 second mark');
        break;
      case 15:
        console.log('15 second mark');
        break;

      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<video id="ssvid" controls width="300">
  <source src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs34s3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: i need to show a `h1` at different `timestamps` how do i make it opacity on and off  in place of `console.log` i tried many variations but it not working.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try using the video `currentTime` property inside a timer. There is also supposed to be a `progress` event. It is outlined in this document:
https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Something like this may work:

```
    // maybe you can select this by id in jQuery rather than DOM
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],
    lastPf // reference for slide away;

video.onprogress = function() {
    PauseFunctions.forEach(function(pf) {
        if (video.currentTime > pf.SecondMark) {
            if (lastPf !== undefined) {
                // slide away the previous thing
                lastPf.OnSlideAway();
            }

            // slide to the new one
            pf.OnSlideTo();
            lastPf = pf;
        }
    });
};
```

Do you think that will work?

Comment: I tried to use something like `$('ssvid').on('progress', ...)` in my experiment but it didn't work. Maybe that will work better though.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36439792/1754507) by @zer00ne is nearly there.  timeupdate doesn't update every second, it's dependent on the user agent.  So, we shouldn't be self incrementing a tick, we should just pass the latest currenttime which represents the current playback time in seconds.

**According to Mozilla:**

- **timeupdate frequency:**

The timeupdate event is fired when the time indicated by the currentTime attribute has been updated.

The event frequency is dependent on the system load, but will be thrown between about 4Hz and 66Hz (assuming the event handlers don't take longer than 250ms to run).

- **currenttime:**

A double-precision floating-point value indicating the current playback time in seconds.

If the media is not yet playing, the value of currentTime indicates the time position within the media at which playback will begin once the play() method is called.

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).